# how to change the activities title *Respectively* in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

hey i wanna do something on discord.js but just don't know how, i know that it's possible but idk how so i wanted to ask ya guys that:
i wanna set my bot's activity like it's keep being changed **respectively** not **randomly**.
it shouldn't be randomly because....uhhh....you'll realize soon ._.

here's my activity's codes **but it's in randomly**(i want it to be respectively as i said):

```
client.on("ready") {
        console.log('Boom bot is ready to boom!')
        setInterval(() => {
            var v = (client.guilds.cache.size)
            const count = [
                "1", "2", "3", "BOOM!"]
            // here it collects the titles in randomly
            const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*(count.length))
            const activity = count[number]
            
            client.user.setActivity(activity);
        };
    })
```

if anybody here knows how to get the numbers of *number* variable **respectively**, plz consider helping this guy

Comment: By respectively do you mean change the bot's activity in order of the count array?

Comment: yes! like it changes from 1 to 2 then 3 then boom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a couple things: declare the desired statuses outside of the setInterval function. Also set an interval in ms for the interval to execute on. This is done by adding a comma and then the number of milliseconds to wait before executing again. Declare the desired index outside of the function and then inside the function reset the index to zero once you've iterated through the whole array.

```
const count = ["1", "2", "3", "BOOM!"] //removed outside
let index = 0; //declaring an index
setInterval(() => {
            // here it collects the titles in randomly
            const activity = count[index] //accessing array at index
            index++; //incrementing
            if (index >= count.length) index = 0; //resetting
            console.log(activity);
            }, 1000); //setting an interval
```

Comment: Define the count array, which contains your desired activities inside of the array, outside of the setInterval. Then access those activities from within the interval

Comment: YEAH! it worked! uh god i knew that it's gonna be verry easy but i didn't know how, thx a bunch buddy✨